# How to get LOG_DAEMON syslog messages available via asl

Tags: macos, mojave, logs

I am attempting to run unbound on my macOS Mojave. This works. I can also log from unbound to a file. That works. But I want to log to syslog.

Unbound logs to the LOG_DAEMON (daemon) facility.

So I added the following in a file `/etc/asl/org.macports.daemon`:

```
# LOG_DAEMON/daemon facility messages are stored and in a file 
> /var/log/daemons.log mode=0644 format=bsd rotate=seq compress file_max=5M all_max=50M
? [= Facility daemon] claim only
? [= Facility daemon] store
* file /var/log/daemons.log
```

And sent SIGHUP to syslogd. I also temporary put

```
= debug 1
```

at the start of `/etc/asl.conf` so to get asl debug information in `/var/log/syslogd.log`. There it says:

```
module: org.macports.daemon
  output         data: NULL
  output       /var/log/daemons.log
    rules: 1
    dest: (none)
    format: bsd
    time_format: lcl
    flags: 0x0000401c (rotate coalesce compress)
        rotatation style: [base=daemons].[ext=log].<sequence>
    ttl: 7 days
    mode: 0644
    file_max: 5242880
    all_max: 52428800
    uid: 0
    gid: 80
  claim         Q [= Facility daemon] only
  store         Q [= Facility daemon]
  file          Q [. ] /var/log/daemons.log
```

But while I know that unbound is syslogging to LOG_DAEMON, nothing shows. Not in Console.app, not in `/var/log/daemons.log`. It is a black hole.

I am able to use `logger` to send LOG_DAEMON messages and these show up in Console.app:

```
default 16:17:23.352674 +0200   sudo       sysbh : TTY=ttys001 ; PWD=/opt/local/etc/unbound ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/logger -p daemon.error GERBENLOG Test message error.daemon
default 16:17:23.359816 +0200   logger  GERBENLOG Test message error.daemon
```

But `/var/log/daemons.log` is not created, and no LOG_DAEMON messages are to be found anywhere. I'm out of options. Does this work at all?